# webpack -w 使用時に、ファイルごとのコンパイル結果を出力させたくない

Tags: webpack

webpackでTypeScriptとSCSSをビルドしようとしています。
双方とも複数のファイルで構成しており、ビルド時に１つのファイルにバンドルさせようとしています。

このとき、コマンドラインから「webpack」と入力したときは期待通りにコンパイルを行なうのですが、「webpack -w」でファイル監視させ、tsファイルやscssファイル変更時に自動リビルドした際、変更したファイルのみのコンパイル結果が、同じディレクトリに作られてしまいます（Main.tsと同じところにMain.jsができてしまう）。これとは別に、バンドルしたファイルも作られますが、こちらには問題はありませんでした。

tsファイル、scssファイルごとに作られるファイルは不要なので出力させないようにしたいのですが、どのように設定すればいいでしょうか？

＜追記＞
その後調査したところ、こちらはwebpackに原因があったのではなく、使用していたcloud9のace editorの設定によって発生していたことがわかりました。
（「ビルド時に自動的にタブを保存して閉じる」のチェックを外すと発生しなくなりました）

Comment: 追記に書いたものを回答として書いて、その回答を採用してください。それがスタックオーバーフロー推奨の作法です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

＜追記＞
その後調査したところ、こちらはwebpackに原因があったのではなく、使用していたcloud9のace editorの設定によって発生していたことがわかりました。
（「ビルド時に自動的にタブを保存して閉じる」のチェックを外すと発生しなくなりました）

Comment: 投稿より48時間たたないと採用できませんので、しばらくお待ちください